# ¿Cómo guardar el checked de un input y crearlos dinámicamente?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Estoy haciendo una página de Anime como tipo Lista en la cual quiero guardar los capítulos que ya estén vistos y poder cambiarlos con un `input` de estado **Visto** a **No Visto.**

Cómo en esta imagen:

[image: Vista Previa]

Quiero que haga esa animación y se mantenga guardado el valor de `checked` del `input` al dar click:

```html
<ul class="collection">
  <li class="collection-item avatar">
    <img src="miniatura.jpg" alt="Miniatura" class="circle">
    <span class="title">1. Título</span>
    <p>Segundo Título.<br>
      Tercer Título.</p>
    <div class="secondary-content">
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Ya tengo el botón listo con la animación, solo me faltaría agregar algo que me pueda permitir guardar el valor `checked` de los **inputs** y cuando yo entre a la página, solo con un click, cambie el estado del `checked` a **no visto.**

También estuve haciendo pruebas con un código que me permita agregar **inputs** de forma más dinámica, pero soy muy nuevo en esto, que no se cómo desarrollarlo.

```js
function addElement(texto) {
  var content = document.getElementById("content");
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  label.innerHTML = texto;
  input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  input.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
  content.appendChild(label);
  content.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<label for="texto">Agregar:</label>
<input id="texto" type="text" size="40/">
<input type="button" onclick="addElement(getElementById('texto').value);" value="Agregar Elemento">
</form>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Si me ayudan u orientan que debo investigar para lograrlo sería de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Tienes que usar javascript. Necesitas una función a la que le pases el id del cápitulo que quieres marcar como visto o no visto y llamar a esa función en el evento onclick de cada uno de los checkboxes ( pasando a la función el id correspondiente al cápitulo al cual pertenece el checkbox ). La función lo que debería hacer es, dependiendo de si el checkbox está marcado o no, mediante AJAX o similares, hacer un POST o GET a un archivo php donde actualices en base de datos el estado del capitulo ( visto / no visto ) en funcion del id que le mandes.

Comment: @IbaiA. Gracias por darme instrucciones para tener una idea de como hacerlo, en lo de la base de datos puede funcionar el localstorage como alternativa?

Comment: Puedes usar la base de datos, la session de php, cookies, localstorage, lo que sea que quieras realmente. Simplemente ten en cuenta que cookies, localstorage, etc, si el usuario borra los datos de navegación, cookies, conecta desde otro dispositivo, etc, no tendrá los datos guardados, mientras que guardando en base de datos si. Eso ya depende de como quieras tu que sea la funcionalidad.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces voy a trabajar en ello.